# Swing animation with depth

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, i have a pop up banner that jumps every time the user gets a notification from the server, this pop up looks like a sign attached with strings to the top of the screen (not code strings lol).

I'm trying to achieve a swing animation, but not from side to side! back and forth, so acutely the bottom yz point should change, so it looks like the popup sign is coming towards the user, and then back, and so on....

I hope i was clear with my question, this matter is bugging me for a long time now.. thanks! !

**Edit**

So i've added a image (really really badly draws, sorry about that), that descrices the effect im trying to achieve :

http://s1.postimg.org/hox4ly3sv/Draw_Sign.png

And again, sorry about the bad drawing.

This is the code i did so far:

```
// container
CALayer *container = [CALayer layer];
container.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:container];


//Create a Plane

CALayer *purplePlane = [self addPlaneToLayer:container
                                        size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)
                                    position:CGPointMake(250, 150)
                                       color:[UIColor purpleColor]];



[container addSublayer:imageView.layer];


 //Apply transform to the PLANE
 CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
 //Add perspective!!!
 t.m34 = 1.0/ -100;
 //t.m34 = 1.0/ -500;
 t = CATransform3DRotate(t, degToRad(45.0), 0, 1, 0);

 purplePlane.transform = t;


CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
// transform.m34 = 1.0 / -50;
container.transform = transform;

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0.8 * M_PI / 2, 100, 100, 0.2)],
                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0 * M_PI / 2, 100, 100, 0.2)],
                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, -0.6 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 0.2)],
                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 0.2)],
                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0.3 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 0.2)],
                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 0.2)],
                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, -0.1 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 0.2)],
                    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 0.2)],



                    // [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 2 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 5)],
                    //   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 3 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 100)],
                    //   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 4 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 100)],
                    nil];
animation.duration = 5;
[container addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
```

As you will notice, in my code, there is no effect of the view swinging towards you, and that's what i'm looking for.

Thanks, Cheers

Comment: Can you post some existing code?

Comment: You probably want a perspective transform. Animate between two transforms. One that makes the view look swung back and the other making it look swung forward.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you are looking for an zoom in / out animation, something like:

```
UIView *theStrigViewThing = ...

[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            [theStrigViewThing setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                [theStrigViewThing setTransform: CGAffineTransformIdentity];
            } completion:nil];
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is not what i've been looking for.. this animation simply makes the hole view larger, and smaller.

Comment: The animation i'm trying to accomplish is, if you can imagine standing in front of a swing, will it swings closer, and then gets far from you. The button part of the view is the on that should acutely animate, the x stays the same.

Comment: I don't see how things can get "further away" without x changing as well, then it will silly look thinner / fatter.

Maybe i'm not getting something, but it sounds like you need to add change in the y direction to the above resize animation as well to achieve the look of things "swinging"

Answer (score 0):

*Might be you are looking Swing Animation on control something like:*

```
func AddSwingAnimation() {
        let offerLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 80, width: self.view.bounds.size.width-40, height: 30))
        self.view.addSubview(offerLbl)
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
        animation.keyPath = "transform.rotation"
        animation.values = [0, 0.3*0.2, -0.3*0.2, 0.3*0.2, 0]
        animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
        animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(1.0)
        animation.isAdditive = true
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + CFTimeInterval(0.5)
        self.offerLbl.layer.add(animation, forKey: "swing")

    }
```

**Enjoy:)**